# Spark AR Studio give me a a error but I haven't errors

Tags: javascript, facebook, instagram, spark-ar-studio

I created this simple patch and a script, in both of them I have no errors or warnings, but Spark AR does not give me the possibility to start the filter and it gives me this error: "Please check the patch graph and try again". Anyone know how I can fix it?

[patch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEqMz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a know bug with Spark, hopefully it will get fixed soon. For now, try to delete your "Variables from Script" and recreate it to fix the problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks this has solved, I take this opportunity to ask you another thing, in the filter I have more rectangles (currently two) in the script I use TouchGestures.onTap (rectangles1) and TouchGestures.onTap (rectangles2), the problem is that by making a tap on a rectangle they start the functions of both (the rectangles are not superimposed)

Comment: @rndUsr Please make a separate question for this issue, since it's unrelated to this one :)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this error occurs when the data types in the patches do not match. The "Subtract" patch for input requires a Number type. Make sure that the data type "Number" (Scalar) is configured in the script. When everything is fixed, try clicking the restart filter button.

Answer (score 0):

deleting all the FromScript nodes on the script patch, then adding them again solved this for me. Major PITA